# Create scanning animation using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

i'm having troubles creating a scanning animation on my android application.For instance, i have come across this application '[Fingerprint love scanner prank](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dansyosoftwares.fingerprintlovetestprank)' which has the scanning animation and i would like to implement the same on my android app. I have tried to implement the same on my android application but in vain.  This is my android code snippet.

**Animation.Java Activity**

```
          scan.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


                    final CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            scanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.progress);
                            scanner.startAnimation(anim1);


                        }

                        public void onFinish() {

                            scanner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    }.start();
                    return false;
                }


            });
```

**Animation.xml**

Contains the scanner image defined by the imageView as shown below

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/scan"
            android:background="@drawable/bgscanner">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/scanner"
                android:id="@+id/scanner1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

**My Animation drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800"
        />
</set>
```

My big issue is, on touch event, the animation does not execute. That is, the image bar does not oscillate along the vertical axis. I kindly request any assistance from stackoverflow

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edited**

This problem can be solved with a very small code.

First, change your XML animation code to this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="false">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        />
</set>
```

Your layout should be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity, the code can be like this:

```
LinearLayout imageView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image);
        final View bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bar.startAnimation(animation);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And this way you are going to have this result:

[image]

I used a View instead of a ImageView to make the scan bar, but you can change the code to your needs.

I hope it helps!

**EDIT 2:**

If you want the animation to happen only if your image is pressed, change the code to this:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bar.startAnimation(animation);
            } else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                animation.cancel();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

It you trigger the animation when the image is pressed (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) and it is going to stop the animation when the image is released (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

Comment: Thanks Leandro ... it worked  ... how can you make it to be continous

Comment: Do you mean make it repeat infinitely? Change the android:repeatCount=4 to android:repeatCount="infinite". If you want to show the animation only when the image is pressed, follow the EDIT 2

Comment: Fabulous! Thank You mate :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of countDownTimer use value animator for the animation in onTouch listner.

```
scan.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   if(motionEvent.getAction==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ 
     ValueAnimator valueAnimator=ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,75);
     valueAnimator.setDuration(4000);
     valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
     valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
           scanner.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            scanner.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
             scanner.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
         }
        });
     valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()      {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
              float translate= (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
              scanner.setTranslationY(translate);//translate scanner in Y direction
           }
       });
    valueAnimator.start();
   }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Now, the animation bar is getting off focus. It hides from the view on touch event

Answer (score 4):

For animation on android , i advice you to use Animation Drawable , it's simple to implement : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html
First steps to display a animation  (Gif by example) , we split it to pngs (online by example i have use http://ezgif.com/ , then i apply the initialisation on xml drawable :

```
<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png through wheel5.png
     files inside the res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

Finally i load it on my defined class :

```
// Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
 // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

change your animation to this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    duration="4000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fillAfter="false">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

and your code

```
scan.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                            scanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.progress);
                            anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                scanner.setVisibility((View.INVISIBLE)
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                                }
                            });
                            scanner.startAnimation(anim1);

                 }
            });
```

Comment: Still it is not working . What im i not doing?? Please assist. I'm really stuck

Comment: better describe your problem. _Still it is not working_ isnt very helpfull

Comment: The animation bar still does not oscillate, it remains on the same position

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

      final CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

     anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.progress);

    // set animation listener
    anim1.setAnimationListener(this);

    // button click event
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTick(View v) {
            scanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // start the animation
            scanner.startAnimation(anim1);
        }            
    });

}
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // Take any action after completing the animation

    // check for fade in animation
    if (animation == anim1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```